# Unity broken after attempted program install

Tags: 11.04, unity, python

I followed these ( http://blog.mypapit.net/2011/05/howto-mining-bitcoin-in-ubuntu-using-opencl-py.html ) directions without any error and now the launch bar for unity is no longer displayed. Can someone help?

unity --reset results in the following error

```
unity-panel-service: no process found
Backend     : gconf
Integration : true
Profile     : default
Adding plugins
Initializing core options...done
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 1
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 1
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 1
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 1
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 1
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Initializing bailer options...done
Initializing detection options...done
Initializing composite options...done
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXCreateContext failed
Compiz (bailer) - Info: Ensuring a shell for your session
zaeb@J0KER1:~$ Cannot register the panel shell: there is already one running.
```

Comment: use unity --reset

Comment: Did you make any changes to your graphics drivers when updating your system?  Is there any interesting errors related to DRI or GLX in `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`?  Does the X server start up properly when you aren't running the OpenCL program?

Comment: I haven't made any changes to the graphics drivers. Unsure how to check for errors, although I searched the log file and it came up empty. How can I check to see if X server starts up properly?

Comment: The output from your `unity --reset` run indicates that your X server isn't advertising the `GLX` extension (one of the extensions exposing the OpenGL API).  My hypothesis is that the OpenCL application is blocking access to the GPU for the X server.  If that is the case, I would expect to see some note about that in the X server log file.

Comment: Well I was messing around more with it and thought I'd reinstall all the xserver files from synaptics which was a bad idea. So instead of trying to fix the computer from not booting I just reinstalled 10.10 and upgraded. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

compiz --replace will probably fix that.